# Which movie shows Naruto and Hinata's wedding?

Tags: naruto

I have completed watching *Naruto* anime series completely, but Hinata's and Naruto's wedding is not shown properly.

So which movie should I watch to see their wedding?

Answer (score 7):

The Last: Naruto the movie.

At the end of the movie in the credits, you can see the images of the wedding.

You also see the events leading up to the wedding, till the bride and groom come out to the ceremony, in the last few episodes of Naruto Shippuden. Episodes 494 to 500.

However, we cannot see the actual happenings anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I watched episodes 479-500, it's about what everyone goes through to get the wedding gifts. It explains everything and leads up to the wedding day, unlike the ending of the movie *The Last: Naruto the Movie*.

I would recommend to watch the movie before watching those episodes.

Comment: um shouldn't it be the other way round?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately outside of the credits from The Last and the events leading up to them walking out there isn't really anywhere to see the actual events after they walk out. I would second what the person above me said and say watch The Last around 480 then wrap up the series. Makes the wedding feel less sudden as far as how the anime flows.